Is this sequence $\frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{n^2(a_n^2 z + a_n b_n)}$ converges to -1
Assumption: $a_n>0$ and $b_n \in \mathbb{R}$, $z\in \mathbb{H}$ upper half plane. We know $a_n \rightarrow 0$ and $\lim_n \frac{b_n}{a_n} = c<\infty$
Consider sequence of function of the form
$$
f_n(z) = \frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{n^2(a_n^2 z + a_n b_n)}
$$
Question:
Is it possible to choose $a_n, b_n$ in such a way so $f_n \rightarrow -1$ constant function uniformly in compact set of $\mathbb{H}$?
Attempt:
My guess is no. Suppose $n^2 a_n^2 \rightarrow a_\infty \neq 0$ and $a_\infty<\infty$, then the imaginary component $\Im(n^2(a_n^2 z + a_n b_n))$ does not disappear in the limit , which imply $f_n$ either converge to $\infty$ or some value that has imaginary component, not what we seek.
Similarly if $n^2 a_n^2 \rightarrow \infty$ then $\Im(n^2(a_n^2 z + a_n b_n)) \rightarrow \infty$, thus $\frac{1}{n^2(a_n^2 z + a_n b_n)} \rightarrow 0$ and $f_n \rightarrow \infty$.
Therefore the only possibility is $n^2a_n^2 \rightarrow 0$. At this point I am stuck...

This is impossible.  Suppose the expression is $-1+e_n$ with $e_n\to 0$. Multiplying by $n^2 a_n^2$ we get
$$n^2 a_n (1+a_n-a_n e_n) =\frac1{z + \frac{b_n}{a_n}}$$
that is
$$n^2a_n=\frac1{(z + \frac{b_n}{a_n})(1+ a_n-a_n e_n)}\,.$$
It follows that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2a_n = \frac1{z+c}\,,$$
but the lhs is independent of $z$, a contradiction.

More simpy: if $f_n(z)\to-1$ then $a_nf_n(z)\to0$, i.e. $\frac1{n^2(a_nz+b_n)}\to1$, or equivalently
$$n^2a_n\to\frac1{z+c}.$$

very minor sign mistake in the first equation of the answer, RHS should have negative, which give your expression @AnneBauval. Overall the answer is correct, so I accept it

@AnneBauval thanks fixed.
